# Передача данных

Tags: php, jquery, get

Требуется сделать передачу данных через url из qr кода. Каким методом лучше это реализовать, через GET или через хеш jquery?

Comment: Вы хотите закодировать урл в qr коде 


Comment: да хочу ___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Google Chart API](http://www.cognation.net/QR/Google_api.htm).